# Retrieve dataset from preferred table first

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with two similar data columns:

```
select name, location 
FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME1, LOCATION2
FROM TABLE2
```

I need to COMBINE the data from table1 and table2.
but, in the output, for a given name, the location value should come from table2 (if present) else it should come from table1. Order of precedence for location field is table2 and then table1.

I tried coalesce but cannot execute it.

```
SELECT NAME, COALESCE(TAB1.LOCATION2, TAB1.LOCATION1 
FROM (
      SELECT NAME, LOCATION1 
      FROM TABLE1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT NAME1, LOCATION2
      FROM TABLE2
      )v
```

Any insight would help a lot.

Comment: Would the location values always be the same for two names in the two tables, or could the locations be different?  Please add sample data here for best results.

Comment: 'I tried coalesce but cannot execute it' - missing bracket after coalesce and alias in coalesce should be v not tab1,

Comment: The location in `table2` may not present because of: (a) no row for this `name` (b) the name is present but the `location` column is NULL. Do you need the value to be taken from `table1` in both cases?

Comment: *I tried coalesce but cannot execute it.* Add a bracket. Add DISTINCT.

Comment: If location for same name is null in both tables do you discard?, if name only exists in one table do you discard?

Answer (score 0):

One approach, using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH source AS (
    SELECT name, location, 1 AS pos FROM TABLE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, location, 2 FROM TABLE2
),
cte AS (
    SELECT name, location, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY pos) rn
    FROM source
)

SELECT name, location
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The use of `ROW_NUMBER` here ensures that only names from `TABLE1` are included in the output, unless they are present only in `TABLE2`.